# Formatting Time after clocks change

Tags: apex, visualforce, email-template, force.com-sites, timezone

**Background**

I have a simple apex function which returns a date time formatted using a time zone:

```
public String getFormattedDatetime() {

    TimeZone tz = UserInfo.getTimeZone();

    return dateTimeValue.format(dateTimeFormat, tz.toString());
}
```

This function is used inside a `Visualforce` email template, and the email is generated by a `Site Guest User`.

The `Site Guest User` had it's `Time Zone` set to `GMT`

But recently, the clock changed in the UK, and we are now on `BST`

So all the times in the emails being generated wrong.

**Question**

1. Is there a way to ensure Salesforce always issues emails using the correct Time Zone, without having to remember to update the `Time Zone` on the `Site Guest User` profile?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the correct time zone to use when formatting all Site Guest User e-mails is British time, then choose **British Summer Time (Europe/London)** on that user account always. That should give you +00:00 in the winter and +01:00 in the summer.